# Contain and substitute

Tags: r, gsub

It is possible substitute a word in a column that contains specific characters?
I would like to change the character "osa" in the set. What can I do?

```
iris
iris$Species <- gsub(contains("osa"), "set", iris$Species, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? `setset` or `set` ?

Comment: I expected only set

Comment: Where is the "contains" coming from? If tidyverse then it is supposed to be used for selecting columns, not for the values within a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *grepl* to find which rows to update, then assign:

```
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

table(iris$Species)
# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     50         50         50 

iris$Species[ grepl("osa", iris$Species, fixed = TRUE) ] <- "set"

table(iris$Species)
# set versicolor  virginica 
#  50         50         50
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: To return only *set*. You can use the `.*` wildcard before and after your pattern (though in your particular example you only need it before)

```
table(gsub(".*osa.*", "set", iris$Species))
#
#       set versicolor  virginica 
#        50         50         50
```

Original answer:

`gsub()` already looks across the whole string for the pattern.

```
gsub("osa", "set", iris$Species, fixed = TRUE)

 table(iris$Species)
#
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#        50         50         50 
 table(gsub("osa", "set", iris$Species, fixed = TRUE))
#
#    setset versicolor  virginica 
#        50         50         50
```

Comment: Sorry, I think it was clear I expect only set

Comment: No problem. This can be done with wildcard matching